# Need a new workaround to view images in MS Word draft mode

Tags: microsoft-word, images

When MS created the `.docx` format for Word in 2007, it disabled viewing images in draft mode. I've read that the reason for this was to keep draft mode light and fast. I'm all for efficiency, but this change was a catastrophe for me because I routinely work in draft mode and need to be able see my images without having to switch to a different view mode.

I eventually [found a quirky workaround](https://web.archive.org/web/20160527061058/http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/125849-Make-objects-visible-in-Draft-View-Word-2007) whereby I could view images in draft mode if I first pasted them into MS Paint, then copied them from Paint into a table in Word. Doing this would insert an `Embed PBrush` field into Word, and that field was an image that was visible in draft mode. That field could then be copy/pasted out of the table and was still visible. I could even convert the field to its value with `Ctrl-Shft-F9`, which eliminated the field and reduced the file size by a factor of 1/3, and the image was still visible.

I've been using that strange workaround successfully for nine years.

Now, MS has been updating Paint with AI and layers and other fancy features and that trick is no longer working for me. When I copy/paste an image from Paint into a table in Word, it does not paste as a field, and it is not visible in draft mode.

This is a new catastrophe. The old images pasted before are still visible, but I no longer have a way to insert new images into Word so that they will be visible in draft mode.

I've done a new search on the issue and found some suggested solutions, none of which appear to work:

- [A Super User answer from 2022](https://superuser.com/questions/152091/how-to-display-images-in-draft-view-in-word-2007#1748155) says to insert the image from a file as an object. I tried this, and got an icon and the filename instead of the image, even though I did not check "Insert as icon".
- [An answer in 2023](https://superuser.com/questions/152091/how-to-display-images-in-draft-view-in-word-2007#1790622) to that same question says the previous answer no longer works and seems to say what to do instead, but I can't figure out what it's telling me to do!
- An [article by Word guru Allen Wyatt](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T005964_Making_Pictures_Show_in_Word.html), updated in 2020, explains the layered structure of Word files and says we can see images in draft mode if we put them on the text layer by setting the text wrapping to "inline with text". I tried that and still could not see the image in draft mode.
- An [answer on the PC Review forum](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-can-i-get-images-to-display-in-draft-view.3118442/#post-10593183) way back in 2007 said that if a file is saved as Word 2003 (`.doc`), it can be opened in Word 2007 and the images will be visible in draft mode. I tried this and found it to be true. But when I then saved that file as `.docx`, closed and reopened it, NONE of the images were visible in draft mode, even the ones that had been visible before saving it as `.doc`. This does, however, suggest a new workaround of going back to working with my files in `.doc` format instead of `.docx`. I'm reluctant to do that, however, because the `.doc` format is so old that it seems like a bad idea to use it now.

Does anyone know what's going on here, enough to know how to again be able to insert an image in Word so that it's visible in draft mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the old workaround. What I mean is that I found a place to download the old MS Paint, which allows me to do what I was doing before.

I found a lot of traffic on Google by people who want to replace the new Paint with the old one. I didn't want to do that. The new features might be good for something -- I don't know yet. But I want the old Paint back mainly for pasting images in Word. So I downloaded the old Paint, not to replace the new, but to run separately.

The place I found to get it is [www.Win7Games.com](https://www.Win7Games.com).

That site primarily offers a download of old games from Windows 7 to run on later versions of Windows, all the way up to 11. But it also offers old versions of a number of other, more useful, Windows tools, and one of them is Paint. I was pretty scared of downloading this thing, but I searched and found several places recommending it and no one saying anything bad about it. So I crossed my fingers and downloaded it.

The download is a zip file containing just one file, an exe. I had SentinelOne scan it, and it reported no problems. So I ran it. Like a lot of old software, it told me to close everything before proceeding. I placed the program in its own folder and did not disable the default Paint. After installation, I pulled up the Start menu and typed "Paint". That brought up both Paint and a new item, "Paint (classic)". I ran each of them and they appear to function independently and both appear to work properly.

Most importantly, I then tested the old Paint by copying an image into it, then copy/pasting the image from there into a Word table. Voila! It pasted as the old `embed PBrush` field. I copy pasted that out of the table and switched to draft mode, and there was my image, visible!!!

Phew! I have managed to restore my routine MS Word draft-mode workflow, including this clunky method of seeing images.

One other comment: I'm not alone in my frustration with Word not displaying images in draft mode. The question of how to get Word to display them is all over the Internet, ever since 2007. Most of the time, the answer is, "You can't" or even "It's impossible." A lesson from this experience, like that of the Wright Brothers on a more profound level, is to be careful about believing it when someone tells you something can't be done!